# What are the risks to Google Container Registry if the project name is changed?

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-container-registry

I have a CI/CD pipeline configured where Google Cloud Build automatically builds containers from code pushed to a GitHub repo if tagged with a specific tag. The containers are automatically deposited into Google Container Registry. Each container in the registry is tagged with a tag in the form `us.gcr.io/project_name/container_name:tag_name`

My question is if I change the project name, how will this affect the containers currently sitting in Google Container Registry that I have already tagged with the current project name? Do I need to change the tag on each container with the intended project name before updating the project name itself? Is this handled automatically by GCP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Registries in Container Registry are named by the host and project ID](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/overview#registry_name). To work with images (for example push, pull, delete) identify the image using the following format:

[HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]:[TAG]

Or [HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]@[IMAGE_DIGEST]

Even if you change your PROJECT NAME, PROJECT ID can’t be changed, because [Project ID: a unique identifier for your project, composed of the project name and a randomly assigned number](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#identifying_projects). So your images keep with the same registries in Container Registry.  us.gcr.io/project_id/container_name:tag_name

Comment: thanks for your answer. I got confused because my project-id was named as a lowercase version of my project name.